# How to display latest 5 orders by using for loop in jinja (django)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

The code below will display all the orders but now I want to display only 5 latest orders in my template. Can anyone explain to me how can I iterate only 5 latest orders through jinja?

**code**

```
<div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Date Orderd</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
                {% for i in orders %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.product}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.date_created}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_order' i.id %}">Update</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_order' i.id %}">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr> 
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: could you please share code inside `views.py`

Answer (score 2):

you can try `groupby` in **jinja** as shown [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#groupby) and limit the loop to only 5 count

## OR

if you are passing any dictionary containing your model data, from `views.py`, you can order the data and limit amount of orders like

```
from your_model.models import your_model_class
def your_view(request):
    orders = your_model_class.objects.order_by('-Date Orderd')[:5]
    # used - for reverse order, and took only 5 orders using [:5]
    context = {
        'orders': orders
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way to solve this is to query last 5 items from your database in you `views` and pass it in context to template.
query..

```
 last_five = TableName.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5][::-1]
```

You can use the second option if you still wants it.
You can use if statement in jinja format. to display last 5 items only.

Firstly, query all obejects from database in descending order in `views`

```
all_objs = TableName.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

then use if statement in jinja to display last 5 items only. as follow.

templates

```
{% for obj in all_objs %}

   {% if forloop.counter <= 5 %}

       <h4>{{obj}}</h4>

   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```